# InnerHTML with special character is trimming the data

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dhtml

InnerHTML with special character is trimming the data.

```
elem.innerHTML = displayedObjects.name;
```

here the `displayedObjects.name` contains a string like `Test&string`. The above statement is assigning the value only `Test`,

What could be done here?

Comment: Hm, somebody already edited this, Why you return to plain text again?

Answer (score 7):

That's because `Test&string` isn't actually valid HTML, because `&` is an escape character for an [HTML entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). If it were properly encoded, it would be `Test&amp;string` instead.

If you're just trying to set the text of an element, I'd suggest you use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) instead:

```
elem.innerText = displayedObjects.name;
```