# Random string HTML escape issue, when using special chars

Tags: javascript, html, random, escaping

I was about to create a little javascript based tool, for quickly generating random strings, with, or without special chars and I found a nice snippet, which greatly inspired me: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52464491/11689422):

```js
function randStr(len) {
  let s = '';
  while (len--) s += String.fromCodePoint(Math.floor(Math.random() * (126 - 33) + 33));
  return s;
}

// usage
console.log(randStr(32));
```

This does the part of the job, when I want alphanumerical strings, with special chars too, but as soon, as I try to embed it into a HTML page, sometimes (actually, pretty frequently), the resulting string is randomly shorter, than the predefined length. It's ok though, when debugging in JS (the string's length is correct), but not on the `html` page, displayed with `.innerHTML` method).
I also tried to use the following code, but the problem is the same:

```js
function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789~!@#$%^&_-+=`|(){}[]:;\"'<>,.?/";
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

console.log(makeid(32));
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: How can we help you debug this part where you're inserting it into HTML if you didn't show us any code where you're inserting it into HTML?  It's really impossible to help you if your'e not showing the problematic code.  I'm going to guess you're concatenating this random string into HTML rather than setting the appropriate inner text or attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML` might yield unexpected results in some situations where your text isn't valid HTML. I recommend you use `innerText` instead.

```js
function makeid(length) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789~!@#$%^&_-+=`|(){}[]:;\"'<>,.?/";
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

 document.getElementById('myid').innerText = makeid(20);
```

```html
<span id="myid"></span>
```

On the difference between `innerHTML` and `innerText` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml)):

> Unlike `innerText`, though, `innerHTML` lets you work with HTML rich text and doesn't automatically encode and decode text. In other words, `innerText` retrieves and sets the content of the tag as plain text, whereas `innerHTML` retrieves and sets the content in HTML format.

An example illustrating the difference between `innerHTML` and `innerText`

```js
var text = "<span>Hey</span>";

document.getElementById('innerHTML').innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById('innerText').innerText = text;
```

```html
<div id="innerHTML"></div>
<div id="innerText"></div>
```

See also this question:
[InnerHTML with special character is trimming the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604572/innerhtml-with-special-character-is-trimming-the-data)

Comment: Thank you very much, this suggestion partially resolved the problem. I said partially, because originally, i also embedded the variable, holding the generated string, into HTML tags and this way, `.innerText` broke those too. At the end, i had to separate them, in order to work both correctly.